# What is the name of the following property of the Lebesgue Integral?

Tags: terminology, lebesgue-integral

I am wondering how to easily refer to the following property of the Lebesgue integral, which holds for any $f\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$ and any $a\neq 0$:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(ax)\, dx=\frac{1}{\vert a \vert }\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \, dx
\end{align*}

For instance, I have names for other basic properties of the integral, like "linearity" and "translation invariance".

Comment: I would call it "dilation property" or something like that.

Comment: [Google seems to agree](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=85n&channel=fs&q=dilation+lebesgue+integral&oq=dilation+lebesgue+integral&gs_l=serp.3..0i8i30k1.1299.1474.0.1931.2.2.0.0.0.0.358.520.0j1j0j1.2.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.2.519...30i10k1.JEuVWvG8d_s).